# Entropy under linear transformation, a measure theoretic proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, statistics

1. Prove that $H(Y)=H(X)+\log(|\det(M)|)$ where $Y=MX$ and 
   $$H(X)=\int_\mathbb{R^d} \log(f(X)) \, dP_X=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \log(f(x)) \, dx$$
   $$H(X)=\int_\mathbb{R^d} log(f(x))f(x) \, dv_S=\sum_{x\in S} \log(f(x))f(x)$$ 
   each is the entropy of a given random variable of a discrete/continuous but absolutely continuous random variable.
2. prove this for general integral $\int \log(\frac{dP}{d\mu*}) \, dP$ where $\frac{dP}{d\mu*}$ is the Random-Nikodym Derivative

I know the fact that $m(MX)=|\det(M)|m(X)$ for Lebesgue Measure $m$ (same of counting measure?)

1. case 1:
   $$H(Y)=\int_\mathbb{R} \log(f(Y)) \, dP_Y=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(f_Y(y)) f_Y(y) \, dy=\text{???}$$

   case 2:
   $$H(Y)=\int_\mathbb{R} \log(f(Y)) \, dP_Y=\sum_{x\in S} \log(f(x))f(x)=???$$
2. For general integral
   $$\int \log \left(\frac{dP}{d\mu*}\right) \, dP=\text{???}$$

How to proceed the proofs? Please give answer in detail